# Integrating Static Library Getting Error "No rule to make target : export_includes needed by import_includes"

Tags: android, embedded-linux

I am facing issue while integrating static library with existing shared library on Android platform (Lollypop)

I am trying to add a static library(.a) in Android L which will be linked to a shared module(.so).
This module already exist (i.e already being built) and i intend to link the static library to this module.

The code structure is as below ::-

```
-ABC
--xxx
--yyy
--zzz [newly added folder]
---Android.mk [newly added]
---foo.c [wrapper file for the library along with header files]
---newlib.a [the actual static lib being discussed]
--Android.mk [This is already present and builds a library which incorporates xxx and yyy say the name of this be oldlib.so]
```

Now i have added zzz folder which contains a static library(newlib.a) and wrapper C file (foo.c).zzz also contains a Android.mk to build itself.

Please check the syntax of both Android.mk

```
Newly Added Android.mk
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := newlib
LOCAL_EXPORT_LDLIBS := -lnewlib
LOCAL_MODULE_SUFFIX := .a
LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS := optional
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := foo.c
LOCAL_SRC_FILES += newlib.a
include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)
```

Syntax of already present Android.mk [I amd highlighting the changes ONLY that i have made for the new added code]

```
NEW_LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(NEW_LOCAL_PATH)/zzz/Android.mk
LOCAL_PATH := $(NEW_LOCAL_PATH)

LOCAL_LDFLAGS := $(LOCAL_PATH)/zzz/newlib.a
LOCAL_WHOLE_STATIC_LIBRARIES := newlib
```

My above configuration results in build error with below error message :-
make:

```
*** No rule to make target 'out/target/product/alpha/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/newlib_intermediates/export_include ',needed
by 'out/target/product/alpha/obj/SHARED_LIBRARIES/oldlib_intermediates/import_include'. stop
```

Could anyone suggest what can the probable reason for the same ?
If more details are required please feel free to ask.
Thanks.

Comment: Can anyone throw some light on the above query ?

Answer (score 0):

I am building android 7.1.2 for google device marlin, the follow solution work for me,

I find a file in `device\google\marlin\libandroid\Android.mk`

```
ifeq ($(TARGET_BUILD_PDK),true)
ifeq ($(TARGET_BOARD_PLATFORM),msm8996)
#----------------------------------------------------------------------
# Fixup libandroid dependency
#----------------------------------------------------------------------
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := libandroid
LOCAL_MODULE_SUFFIX := .so
LOCAL_MODULE_CLASS := SHARED_LIBRARIES
LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS := optional
LOCAL_SRC_FILES_arm := ../../../../$(PRODUCT_OUT)/obj/PACKAGING/pdk_fusion_intermediates/system/lib/libandroid.so
LOCAL_SRC_FILES_arm64 := ../../../../$(PRODUCT_OUT)/obj/PACKAGING/pdk_fusion_intermediates/system/lib64/libandroid.so
LOCAL_MULTILIB := both
include $(BUILD_PREBUILT)
```

so may be it can change that

```
LOCAL_SRC_FILES_arm:= newlib.a
LOCAL_SRC_FILES_arm64:= newlib64.a
LOCAL_MULTILIB := both

LOCAL_MODULE_CLASS := STATIC_LIBRARIES
include $(BUILD_PREBUILT)
```

related link: https://codeantenna.com/a/DCKrTbco0v